# Construct a sphere with python

Tags: python, math, geometry

I am working on a bioinformatics project, where my biological object is a filled sphere.

The package that I am using provides a function that allows us to construct a sphere of points, but the points are only at the surface of the sphere.

Is there, a function, or a method that could help me construction a filled sphere (evenly placed points inside and at the surface of a spherical object).
Here is the code I was working with :

```py
def construct_sphere(num_locations):
    num_pts = num_locations
    indices = np.arange(0, num_pts, dtype=float) + 0.5

    phi = np.arccos(1 - 2*indices/num_pts)
    indices = np.arange(0, num_pts, dtype=float) + 0.5

    phi = np.arccos(1 - 2*indices/num_pts)
    theta = math.pi * (1 + 5**0.5) * indices

    x, y, z = np.cos(theta) * np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi);
    locations = np.array(list(zip(x, y, z)))
    
    return locations
```

Comment: How do you define "evenly placed points"?

Comment: You could for example take the points [2i/n-1, 2j/n-1, 2k/n-1] for i=0..n, j=0..n, k=0..n, discarding those points (x, y, z) with x^2+y^2+z^2 > 1.

Comment: As @hpchavaz pointed out, it depends on how you define evenly placed points. A general approach you could try is composing voronoi cells on the surface and within the ball. It is computationally simple for both cases.

Comment: I mean equidistant points within the sphere